# Docker uses the DNS of the host instead of the DNS mentioned in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: docker, dns, ubuntu-18.04, samba

I am using Ubuntu 1804 and Ihave created an ubuntu docker and configured samba on it. Whenever I run

```
root@dc2:/# host -t A dc2.sample.example.com
```

I get this error

```
 ;; reply from unexpected source: 192.168.0.29#53, expected 172.17.0.1#53
    Host dc2.sample.example.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

192.168.0.29 is the IP of my host machine on the wlps network interface.
172.17.0.1 is the IP of the docker.

The **/etc/resolv.conf** on my **docker** is

```
root@dc2:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 172.17.0.1
search sample.example.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

**ifconfig** within the docker shows this

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:67ff:fe78:f1f1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:67:78:f1:f1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16281  bytes 887008 (887.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24325  bytes 111088731 (111.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp6s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:97:98:71:66:a2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 29556327  bytes 2561211141 (2.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29556327  bytes 2561211141 (2.5 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.29  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::5e1a:ef44:3912:319c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5c:87:9c:c2:77:34  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 97406  bytes 133018627 (133.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28369  bytes 4610340 (4.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

From what I've understood, it is using the wifi(wlp0s20f3) network interface. If I switch off the wifi on my host and run the same command, I get

```
root@dc2:/# host -t A dc2.sample.example.com
;; reply from unexpected source: 127.0.0.1#53, expected 172.17.0.1#53
;; Warning: ID mismatch: expected ID 52940, got 62153
dc2.sample.example.com has address 172.17.0.1
```

I have tried using `--dns 172.17.0.1` while running the docker.

**NOTE**

I am running the docker with

```
sudo docker run -d 
   --net=host
   --dns 172.17.0.1
   -v /etc/krb5.conf:/etc/krb5.conf -v /dev/urandom:/dev/random
   --name kerb
   --cap-add SYS_ADMIN 
   -h dc2 
   --add-host dc2.sample.example.com:172.17.0.1 --add-host dc2:172.17.0.1 
   -e BOOTSTRAP=0 
   kerb:kerb
```

Comment: have you tried removing `--net=host` option?

Comment: @mulg0r I require the host and docker to be on the same network, so I need to keep the --net=host option. I just want the container to use its own DNS configuration.

Comment: You can define docker networks in order to have both docker in the same network; or use host.docker.internal to access from one to other via host ip. `--net=host` is not needed. If you define a docker-network, you can put docker name in resolv.conf better than internal IP.

Comment: @mulg0r Seems to be just what I needed. Thanks for the help. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define docker networks in order to have both docker in the same network; or use host.docker.internal to access from one to other via host ip. --net=host is not needed. If you define a docker-network, you can put docker name in resolv.conf better than internal IP.

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
root@dc2:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver yourdockername
search sample.example.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Create a docker network:

```
docker network create -d bridge mynetwork
docker run --network=mynetwork ...
```

(instead of --net=host) and the rest the same.

That's because if you use `--net=host`, all interfaces in your docker are the same than your host had before `docker run`. Furthermore, you're not mounting `resolv.conf` from your host to your docker, so, it's not possible to route it.
There're other ways to do it, but I recommend you use `docker-proxy` and `docker networks` to do it: creating a vnet and access their docker using docker name instead IP address.